# Windows Mongodb insert test key and remove it to monitor connection

Tags: mongodb, connection, eval, monitoring

I'm still new to Mongo and I'm trying to monitor a connection on my Dev team's Windows computers. One of the suggestions was to create a test key and remove it afterwards - if the test key is not created, then there is a problem with the connection.
This is what I managed to find:

```
mongo db-mydb --eval "db.yourCollection.insert({key:'value'});"
mongo db-mydb --eval "db.yourCollection.update({ key: 'value' }, { $unset : { description : 1} })"
```

To be honest, I'm afraid I may destroy significant data and I'm not even sure if this is the best option. All I need is some command that returns a boolean for the connection status, so I can monitor it remotely.

Comment: Why not just run a query or `db.stats()`?

Comment: Nice question :) 
Guess I didn't think it through. Thank you!